# delete multiple selected items from database via list view?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

how to remove multiple selected items from the database via list view?

I can't find how to do it, I can't find how to get the ide of each selected object, or tell the delete line to delete each selected item

i tried a lot of things but i canot find the way, im new at this so need help :/

I was trying to follow some tutorials but nothing, in line with

```
"db.delete("personajes", "codigo=" + **(HERE)**, null);"
```

I put "list_items" but it throws me an insignificant error to put here, that way clearly it is not, I tried 3 days ago and nothing, I am getting a little frustrated

```
    package com.example.x.basededatos;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;




public class Consultartlista extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TABLAPERSONAJES = "personajes";
    ListView listapersonajes;
    ArrayList<String> listaInformacion;
    ArrayList lea;
    ArrayList<usuario> listaPerso;
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper conn;

    public int id;

/********************/
    ArrayList<String> list_items = new ArrayList<String>();
    int count = 0;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_consultartlista);


        conn=new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,"administracion",null,1);


        listapersonajes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listapersonajes);

        consultarListaPersonas();
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listaInformacion);
        listapersonajes.setAdapter(adaptador);

        /*******/

        listapersonajes.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        listapersonajes.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                count = count + 1;
                mode.setTitle(count + " items seleccionados");

                list_items.add(listaInformacion.get(position));


            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                count = 0;
                MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu1, menu);




                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {



                switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.delete_id:
                    for(String msg : list_items){
                        SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getWritableDatabase();
                        db.delete("personajes", "codigo=" + , null);
                        db.close();
                        adaptador.remove(msg);

                    }
                    Toast.makeText(Consultartlista.this, count + " items removidos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    count = 0;
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                  //  break;

                default:
                    return false;


            }



                //return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

            }
        });


    }



    public void consultarListaPersonas() {
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "administracion", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase BaseDatabase = admin.getWritableDatabase();
        SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getReadableDatabase();

        usuario usuario=null;
        listaPerso=new ArrayList<usuario>();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLAPERSONAJES,null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            usuario = new usuario();
            usuario.setCodigo(cursor.getInt(0));
            usuario.setNombre(cursor.getString(1));
            usuario.setContraseña(cursor.getString(2));

            listaPerso.add(usuario);


        }
        obtenerLista();

    }

    private void obtenerLista() {
        listaInformacion=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<listaPerso.size();i++){
            listaInformacion.add(listaPerso.get(i).getCodigo()+" Nombre: "
                    +listaPerso.get(i).getNombre()+" Contraseña: "
                    +listaPerso.get(i).getContraseña());

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code. First of all, in your *onItemCheckedStateChanged* you need to add the item to your list only if *checked* is true, otherwise you have to remove it from the list. 
Second, your *delete* is incomplete, but I assume that you are trying to concat the id of the item to the where clause, what in your case is wrong because you have a collection. You have to filter your deletion with the list of selected items. The SQL query should be like this:

```
DELETE FROM personajes WHERE codigo IN ('codigo1','codigo2','codigo3')
```

So, your SQLite delete method should look like this:

```
db.delete("personajes", "codigo IN ?" + , String[]{"'codigo1','codigo2','codigo3'"});
```

You just need to create a string with all the ids with single quotes and separated by commas (like an array).

Third, I recommend you to take a look at [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) library. It could help you and solve your problem easily.

Comment: hello, i realize that "codigos" is not a String, is the primary key of my DB, codigos is the id that is inserted from the user manually, not automatic, so, idk how to check the "codigo" from an item checked, i think i dont know how to iterate or dev that, can u help me with that please? thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the ids are strings or integers. You need to pass an array of Strings as third param in the delete method even if they are ints. So your should be something like db.delete("personajes", "codigo IN ?" + , String[]{"'1','2','3'"});. About checked items, you need to validate in _onItemCheckedStateChanged_:
if(checked) {
 list_items.add(listaInformacion.get(position));
} else {
list_items.remove(listaInformacion.get(position));
}
mode.setTitle(list_items.size() + " items seleccionados");

Comment: Hello cesar,  i realized u are from peru asi que podemos hablar un poco español no? jaja, mira aqui en esta caja de comentario no me deja responderte con codigos largos, asi que puse una respuesta debajo , puedes leerla, gracias desde ya!

Comment: lo correcto seria db.delete("personajes", "codigo" + "IN ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(che)}); ya que tienes que filtrar tu consulta por todos los codigos que esten en el array

Comment: Hola, al ponerlo asi tal cual me dices me pone:  (1) near "?": syntax error. syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: DELETE FROM personajes WHERE codigoIN ?

luego lo puse de esta forma
db.delete("personajes", "codigo" + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(che)});
no me crashea , pero no surge efecto el delete, no tengo mucha exp en almacenar en string asi que pienso que estare almacenando mal los valores en ese string..

Comment: le falta un espacio antes del IN, debe ser "codigo" + " IN ?",

Comment: Hola cesar disculpe que estuve off un tiempo por otras razones , escribo tal cual me dices, y sigue diciendome el mismo error, a todo esto creo que tampoco estoy almacenando bien los id no se como hacerlo, y ya intente poner de todas formas con espacios adelante atras y todo y sigue el mismo error, :/